# Prestashop 1.7 - global var doesnt work on CMS page

Tags: variables, prestashop, smarty

How can i check language on CMS page?

I use

```
{if $language.iso_code=='gb'}{/if}
```

on homepage (domain.com/gb/) and it works, unfortunatelly when i use exact same code on other pages (i.e. domain.com/gb/content/11-test) - it fails. Simply print result of {$language.iso_code} is empty, like all others language related vars... I use shortcodes to include my tpl files (and there is my language related code) into CMS pages.

What should i do now? Debug mode says: "Notice: Undefined index: language"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `$language` variable in `themes/your_theme/content/cms/page.tpl` with a code `{if $language.iso_code=='gb'}{/if}`. But it will work for all cms pages, so if you need only particular one you can use `{if $cms.id}{/if}` to detirmine the page.